# How to establish the modus ponens inference rule in the LK sequent calculus for first-order logic?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, formal-proofs, provability, sequent-calculus

How can the *modus ponens* inference rule
$$
\frac{\Gamma \vdash \varphi\hspace{1cm}\Delta\vdash \varphi\rightarrow\psi}{\Gamma,\Delta \vdash \psi}
$$
be established in the LK sequent calculus for first-order logic without resorting to the fact that this calculus is semantically complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that *modus ponens* is derivable in the sequent calculus LK.

In general, an inference rule

$$\dfrac{\Gamma_1 \vdash \Delta_1 \qquad \cdots \qquad \Gamma_n \vdash \Delta_n}{\Gamma \vdash \Delta}(*)$$

is *derivable* in LK if there is a LK derivation of the sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$
starting from the premises $\Gamma_1 \vdash \Delta_1$, $\,\dots\,$, $\Gamma_n \vdash \Delta_n$.
Intuitively this means that the rule $(*)$ can be simulated by the inference rules of LK.

The following shows that *modus ponens* is derivable in LK.

$$\frac{\dfrac{\Gamma \vdash \varphi \qquad \dfrac{}{\psi \vdash \psi}\text{ax}}{\Gamma, \varphi \to \psi \vdash \psi}\to_L \qquad \Delta \vdash \varphi \to \psi}{\Gamma, \Delta \vdash \psi}\text{cut}$$

The idea is that *modus ponens* is an elimination rule for the connective $\to$, and LK can simulate it via the rules $\to_L$ and cut.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I will generalize the result a little, and show that
$$
\dfrac{\Delta \vdash \Sigma, \varphi\rightarrow\psi\qquad\Gamma\vdash\Xi,\varphi}{\Delta,\Gamma\vdash\Sigma,\Xi,\psi}
$$
using a proof that is essentially [the one given by Taroccoesbrocco](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3887480/37058), but a little more detailed:

$$
\dfrac{\Delta \vdash \Sigma,\varphi \to \psi\qquad\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{\psi \vdash \psi}{\text{ax}}}{\dfrac{\Gamma,\psi\vdash\psi}{\dfrac{\psi, \Gamma \vdash \psi}{\dfrac{\psi, \Gamma \vdash \psi,\Xi}{\psi, \Gamma \vdash \Xi,\psi}{\text{x R}}}{\text{wk R}}}{\text{x L}}}{\text{wk L}}\qquad\dfrac{\Gamma \vdash \Xi,\varphi}{\dfrac{\Gamma \vdash \Xi,\varphi, \psi}{\Gamma \vdash \Xi, \psi, \varphi}{\text{x R}}}{\text{wk R}}}{\varphi \to \psi,\Gamma \vdash \Xi,\psi}{\to L}}{\Delta, \Gamma \vdash \Sigma, \Xi,\psi}{\text{cut}}
$$

Comment: Great! Usually, the rule $\to_L$ of LK is considered in his multiplicative version, as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Inference_rules) (this is the version I used in my answer), while you used the additive version, which requires the same contexts in its two premises. The two versions are equivalent, modulo weakening and contraction. In this case, the advantage of the multiplicative version is that weakenings are not needed.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: Oh, I see. I used the inference rules given on pp. 91-92 of Sperschneider & Antoniou's *Logic: A Foundation for Computer Science* (Addison-Wesley, 1991).